# "intck" SAS analogus in Netezza

Tags: sql-server, netezza

Im looking for a way in which I can derive the same results in Netezza if I had used the "intck" function in SAS.

Question eg: INTCK('QTR',FIN_YR,CNT_DATE)+5

What would provide me with the same answer in a SQL-Netzza code.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

select floor(months_between(cntct_date,finyr)/3)+5 as test from tmp01

This works perfect. thanks to a friend

floor is used to remove the fractional portion of the months_between result. "/3" is for the quarter(comprised of 3 months each)